# Install php8.0 on ubuntu 23.04

Tags: linux, server, php-8

i'm trying to install php8.0 on ubuntu 23.04.
first `sudo apt install php8.0` get this error

```
 E: Unable to locate package php8.0
```

when i use PPA package like this:

```
apt install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt update
apt install php8.0
```

i get tis error:

```
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
```

it mean that PPA php package is not released for ubuntu 23.04,

if so, there are an other way to install php8.0 in untubu 23.04 ?

Help please

Comment: Facing the same issue, Please let me know if you / any one figured out any solution?

Comment: You may find a solution if you ask on a more Q&A appropriate site!!   For example on the AskUbuntu stackexchange site.   Remember (boys and girls) that StackOverflow is for **programming** questions.  And installing software is not a programming problem.

Comment: (And for the doubters, read the tagwiki for `[linux]` - *"NOTICE: All Linux questions must be related to programming; those that aren't will be closed."*)

Comment: @ShafiqPasha, dowgrade Os version to ubuntu 22.04